# PHP - How To Bridge Table Using A Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, bridge

I am in the process of building a PHP application. I am fairly new at programming PHP and I’ve been researching on how to bridge table together thru forms however I am not finding anything relevant.

I want the administrator to be able to link multiple jobs from tableA to routes from TableB to a single worker from TableC.

All thru a from. I use mysql for my Database.

Is there a term for this that I should google? Or a code snippet you guys could point me to?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

There are plenty of examples around, and it will be beneficial for you to take a look at [this graph](http://fabzter.com/blog/get/images/sql_joins.jpg).